# How to make a view pop/disappear from right to left if we press back navigation button?

Tags: ios7, segue, popviewcontroller

I have used a custom segue to make a view appear from left to right using:

```
  transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
```

Now after it have appeared, I want to pop it right to left clicking back navigation button.

I have searched and also tried to solve this but not succeed yet.

Comment: Are you using `push` segue   ?

Comment: then by default it will do it..

Comment: Sorry, it is not doing that.

Comment: read this article http://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions-more